# automating excel with win32com on linux with wine

Tags: python, linux, excel, win32com, wine

I have a rather complex Excel 2010 file that I automate using python and win32com.  For this I run windows in virtual box on an ubuntu machine.

However, that same excel file solves/runs fine on Ubuntu Maverick directly using wine 1.3.  Any hope of automating Excel on wine so I can drop the VM?

Or is that just crazy talk (which I suspect).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need a *Windows* version of Python, not a Linux version -- I'm saying you'd have to run Python under wine as well.

Have you tried with just a normal Windows install of Python on wine? I don't see any reason why this wouldn't work.

There is are numerous pages in a Google search that show Windows Python (32-bit) working fine.