# win32com and crossplatform problems

Tags: python, cross-platform, powerpoint, win32com

I'm using win32com with python to generate Automated PowerPoint pptx files.

My scripts are generally ran on window based machines.

Apparently, because I'm using win32com my scripts wouldn't work on other hardware/Operating systems - Max/Linux/other.

Is this really the case? if so, is there a solution?

Comment: Whatever relied on win32com won't work, if it isn't mission critical, just comment out the parts that rely on it.

Comment: As far as I can tell python-pptx has no windows dependencies and should work on Linux as well as on Windows for creating PowerPoint files.

Comment: that's correct python-pptx has no windows dependencies however it's still a fairly young library so its missing bits and bobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use win32com, you are communicating with Windows programs, in this case PowerPoint.

So, no, it won't work without the Windows program, which means it typically won't work without Windows, although you might be able to make it work if you install PowerPoint on WINE and then use the Windows version of Python with it.  There was a question and answer about this technique here:

[automating excel with win32com on linux with wine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847684/automating-excel-with-win32com-on-linux-with-wine)

Other options (that don't require installing PowerPoint on Linux) include automating a cross-platform package like OpenOffice/LibreOffice, or (since you're using Python) using restructuredText and S5 to create slides.

Edit:  As Tris Nefzger points out above, there is a cross-platform Python package designed specifically for creating PowerPoint slides, as well.